# How to define minimum supported screen size with MUI/ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI 5.6 in a webapp that requires large viewport. I want to define a minimum screen width for the entire app such that:

1. If users access the app on devices with smaller width, the app should not resize beyond the defined minimum width.
2. If users access the app on devices with smaller width, show them a warning message that we dont fully support their device.

Is this achievable with MUI, or I need another library for this?

Comment: This should help https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first requirement is achievable through styling and media-queries and can be achievable either with [plain CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_features) or with [MUI-specific styling tools](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/responsive-ui/#main-content).

The second requirement can be implemented with [useMediaQuery hook](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/#main-content) in several ways:

**Restrict users with unsupported devices to use the app**

You can wrap the entire app in a wrapper-component where you define the required min-width

```
  const requiredWidth = useMediaQuery("(min-width:1024px)");
```

Then you can return UI of your App or the screen with a message that the device is not supported:

```
  return requiredWidth ? (
    { children }
  ) : (
    <p>We do not fully support your device </p>
  );
```

In this case, the entire app will be unavailable for the user.

**Show an alert**

Another option is to use the same wrapper component and render an [Alert](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-alert/) or [Snackbar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/) which will be rendered alongside the rest of the UI of your app :

```
  return (
    <>
      {children}
      {requiredWidth && <AlertComponent />}
    </>
  );
```

In this case, a user will be notified about their device but still be able to use the app.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted the answer but still hoping for a more flexible solution. On mobile devices can the website be rendered "as-if" it's running in a larger viewport? I have seen some websites that present desktop view on mobile with a lot of scrolling. MUI being responsive by default is making things challenging for my use-case. Was hoping changing the breakpoint values will help but it didn't.

Comment: What I can think of as a possible solution is to play around with [viewport metatag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) by setting the width attribute to the required min-width and making the website unresponsive on purpose